# Google map cocoa pods integration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I am integrating google maps with cocoa pods. I have done the integration but when i an running the project I Am getting following issue

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/SANDY/Robert/Office/ProjectName/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps', framework linker option at /Users/SANDY/Robert/Office/ProjectName/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraUpdate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCoordinateBounds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPath", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPolyline", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzTripInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TrackOrderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DriverInfoViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DashboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EzAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The warning said it all. You link the framework as a dynamic library, thus it's ignored and not linked, so ld told you symbol cannot be found as it's in the (unlinked) framework.

Comment: so what should i do to make it correct?

Comment: I have no idea how cocoa pods handles it. Personally I use GTL source to access their service. You should provide a sample project so others might be able to help you on this a bit easier.

Comment: @Bruce have you checked answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Find Location of Pods in your App Goto Pods-->GoogleMaps-->FrameWorks select GoogleMaps.framework drag and drop in your project and Build it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have open wrong file. After installing pod You need open project from **.xcworkspace** in place of **.xcodeproject** .

[image]